# Transparency with GifCreator php class not working

Tags: php, image, class, transparency

I try to use the Gifcreator php class to create an animated GIF image from 10 PNG images.
The animated image is created but transparency of original images is lost. I have a black bakground.
The documentation says that the transparency is determinated by first loaded image. The 10 images have a transparent background. I loaded htem in Paint whicj says that it is based on white.

Has anoyone a solution to this ?

Thanks,

The class is here : https://github.com/Sybio/GifCreator

My script here : http://www.egloff.eu/rsmaptest/slideshow.php

The first image here : http://www.egloff.eu/rsmaptest/images/image0.png

The code :

```
<?php
// Include the class
require_once('./testcreator/GifCreator.php');

// Instanciate the class (uses default options with the addition of width/height  specified)
$gif = new GifCreator(0, 2, array(0, 0, 0),550,550);

// Add each frame to the animation
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image9.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image8.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image7.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image6.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image5.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image4.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image3.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image2.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image1.png'), 100, true);
$gif->addFrame(file_get_contents('images/image0.png'), 500, true);


// Output the animated gif
header('Content-type: image/gif');
echo $gif->getAnimation();
?>
```

Comment: Where is the problem with my question ? Where are the comments posted gone ?

Comment: The problem with the question is described in the "on hold"  box. Now that you added the nessecary information I casted a reopen vote. The answer was probably deleted by the author after he realized that it wasn't a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question, and it might help some others using the same library or other libraries based on the same original work by László Zsidi.

In the class, you have to replace the following part that appears in one or another place in 2 lines :

```
$Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ( ( $this->DIS << 2 ) + 0 ) .
```

by this one

```
$Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ((( $this->DIS << 2 )) | 1 + 0 ) .
```

That solved my problem and transparency works now OK. i tried in 3 differents classes i've found are all based on the same work.

I hope this can help.